# How to access jupyter lab on a remote laptop?

Tags: networking, remote-access, jupyter-notebook, jupyterlab

I have a remote laptop and a local laptop. I want to remotely access the resources on the remote laptop via Jupyter Lab programming interface. There are 2 problems needed to be solved:

1. The remote laptop is behind a NAT hence does not have a public IP address. I need to do NAT traversal.
2. I have to establish a Jupyter Lab server that respond to remote requests.

After some searching, I have

1. changed the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500232/10565868).
2. used npm package [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/) to do NAT traversal, i.e. to forward all requests to a provided url to a specified port the remote laptop. Specifically, I run this command `lt --port 8888`, where 8888 is the port that Jupyter Lab runs on.

However when I open the url provided by `localtunnel`, I get 404. I want to know are there better and simpler solutions? or how can I make my method work?

Comment: What problems do you have remaining after you've set up localtunnel and everything?